# Novel about a girl who was transported to a parallel world, where she attended a magic academy

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

Around 2015 to 2016 I started a novel about a girl who was transported to a parallel world and took the place of her parallel self.
In this world, they practice magic. She takes her evaluation test soon after and is revealed as pretty much trash.

She struggles with her studies in the magic academy for a while, and then takes a second test, where it is revealed that she actually has two souls that control different aspects of magic, after which she becomes very powerful. I think her aspects are something like darkness & lightning, with lightning being a super-rare, strongest attack-type aspect.

She moves into a better dormitory with two friends, and then they have to find some more people for some kind of monster-hunting exam or something. That's as far as I got, I think.

I also remember her often mentioning how tall she was. It felt like the author's pet-peeve.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: No, no details. I have no idea when it was published, but I read it probably around 2015-2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Metaworld Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45692613-metaworld-chronicles)* by David J Wuto

> Everyone dreams of reliving oneʼs life, starting over, but when Gwen Song awoke in her fifteen-year-old body, she found herself in a world of urban sorcery. Though her troubled child- hood remained, the familiar society she had once lived in had all but disappeared, replaced by a parallel reality.
>
> Back in her teenage body, she must navigate her new world, once again forging friendships, filial bonds, and gain mastery over the skills necessary to survive in a 21st century Earth ruled by Mages and Magic, where humanity lives in enclaves shielded from Magical Beasts, Demi-humans, and otherworldly beings in a meta-world made unreal by a sorcerous apartheid

Comment: Thank you for giving us the answer, but you'll get more votes if you tell us more about it, like a summary, a link to a review, a picture of the cover, etc.  Also, please don't forget to come back and mark your answer correct in 2 days.

Comment: I honestly never cared much for votes on Stackexchange. I see it as a pointless mechanic.

Comment: ^_^ Alright... then you'll be providing a better, more useful, answer, for this person and anyone in the future?